# Convert record to string with custom delimiter

Tags: postgresql, replace, casting, delimiter, record

I can convert record to string by just doing myrecord::text. My problem is that my record has text fields which contain commas, and the resulting type cast text is comma separated. Thus, I cannot separate the resulting text in a good way.

Solution would be to define a custom delimiter when casting record to text (for example tab or semicolon). How can I achieve this?

Googling gives me answers like use functions string_agg, unnest, array_to_string, etc. None of those functions exist in my installation (I am using PostgreSQL version 12.4 on a Windows machine).

replace(myrecord::text, ',', '\t') puts tab inside of my text fields that should have commas.

Example code:

```
DECLARE
myrecord RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR myrecord IN
SELECT * FROM mytable
LOOP
RAISE INFO '%',replace(myrecord::text, ',', '\t');
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need a tab separated output of the contents of a table, where some columns are text fields that contain commas.

Comment: You can concat(col1,';',col2,';'col3,';'col4,';'col5,';'col6,';')

Comment: @ValNik Interesting, but there is a large number of columns. Would it be possible to unfold the concat for a record type? See example code added in question and please respond as an answer so I can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a tab separated output of the contents of a table, you could use `COPY`:

```
COPY mytable TO '/dir/outfile' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t');
```

Comment: Ah, of course. The example I gave was extremely simplified and I am actually doing lots of stuff in my procedure, but it's not a problem to just save it as a table and then output it with copy. Solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the answer given by @LaurenzAlbe, fully meets your task.

For interest, I will offer another example for copying with direct conversion without an intermediate table.
See this also.

Example for concat all columns with a designated separator.

```
COPY (select string_agg(value,';' order by ordinality)
      from
        (select test_table.id,t.*
         from test, lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(test_table)) with ordinality as t
         where ....
        )x
      group by id
      order by id)
TO '/dir/outfile' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t');;
```

However, the answer is more about concat(....) than about copy ...

To represent whole table row as a  string, where the columns are separated by a comma, you can use the operator `concat(t.*)`.
If there are comma-containing values in the columns of the row, we mast use another delimiter (separator).

Comment: Looks neat, but I get the error (as I said in original question) that string_agg is not a recognized function. Guess it is not included in the Windows version of Postgres?

Comment: I checked it out with PostgreSql 12. ``string_agg`` function included since v.9 as ``string_agg(expression, delimiter)``. I don't understand what could be the mistake, sorry.